# How do I make the search bar work with CNContactPicker when multiple selection is enabled?

Tags: ios9, uisearchcontroller, cncontact

I have project that is using the new `Contacts` framework introduced in iOS 9

Several of my `UITableView` subclasses call up a `CNContactPicker` and I wanted to make use of the search bar that appears at the top.

A couple of these views just implement the delegate method  - `contactPicker:didSelectContact:` and another implements both that method and also  - `contactPicker:didSelectContacts:`, the implementation of which causes the `CNContactPicker` to allow multiple selections.

I made the various classes declare they were `UISearchControllerDelegates` and was delight to see that that was all that was required to make the selection work with my contactPicker delegate methods.

Unfortunately the third view didn't work - you type into the search field and it provides a filter list based on what you typed but when you tap to select, the selection is highlighted but nothing more happens. If I go back to the code and comment out the `contactPicker:didSelectContacts`: method then it works,

Presumably there is a way to make this respond as otherwise the `CNContactPicker` view wouldn't be displaying the search bar when multiple selections were allowed.

What should I be doing to make this work ?

Comment: since noticed that having both didSelectContact and didSelectContacts implemented throws a warning in the log so removed the didSelectContact from the view that needs multiple select. however this doesn't affect the search bar question

Comment: was looking at this today... in Xcode 11.6, what I see is that no search UI appears if I am allowing multi-select of contacts (`didSelectContacts`). Is this what you saw as well?